# What is an appropriate term for this line of study?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Our professor did not give us a syllabus, so we are sort of in the dark when trying to review our lessons. I can not find any video or any article explaining this particle topic of ours:
[image]

The task is to reduce this entire circuit into a single resistor so that we could know the resistance between node A to C. I am having trouble determining which is parallel to which or series to which. There are obvious parts that I can determine, but our professor is talking about "stretching" the circuit in such a way so that it becomes easier to identify which is parallel and which is series.

As the question above, what is a topic that best describes the problem above? Circuit analysis is the closest subject I found, since I am finding the resistance, but there is not an abundance of articles or videos showing techniques of the reduction/simplification of a complex circuit.

Comment: The topic is "series and parallel combinations of resistors".

Comment: Did the course itself have a name?  You might try looking up anything similar to "Electrical Circuit Simplification".

Comment: Re-draw the circuit with all resistors vertical - it should be easier to see what resistors are in parellel with others, and which are in series, so it will be easier to simplify things.  This sort of test circuit is usually drawn in a way designed to confuse the student.

Comment: What is relevant in schematics is what is connected with what, but not how.  The respective underlying branch of mathematics is called graph theory, but this kind of application is not really one where you'd bring out the respective toolboxes unless you were programming a schematic analyzer.  Essentially you need to develop an eye for when two circuit elements are in series (have one common node not shared with other elements) or in parallel (have two common nodes possibly shared with other elements) and apply the respective simplification.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to identify pairs of resistors that are either in parallel or in series. When you identify a pair, collapse it to a single resistor. Repeat until you're down to one resistor.

This procedure doesn't always work, but it does in this case. Even when it doesn't work, it can be a useful simplification in preparation for a more sophisticated analysis.